# e-mail function with html content

Tags: php, html, email

i am trying to send e-mail with html code inside. i have following code;

```
$message ="<html><head><title></title></head><body>test</body></html>"; 
$rmail = $mail_email;
$subject = "subject";
$head = "MIME-Version: 1.0 ";
$head .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8";           
$head .= "Date: ".date("r")." ";
$mail_at=mail($rmail, $subject, $message, $head);
```

but, when i open the mail, mail content is,

```
<html><head><title></title></head><body>test</body></html>
```

it is just sending the string not compile the html code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add newlines in your header

```
 $head = "MIME-Version: 1.0 \r\n";
 $head .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8 \r\n";           
 $head .= "Date: ".date("r")." \r\n";
```

Otherwise the `Content-type` header is on the same line as `MIME-version`which won't work

Mostly `\r\n` works for me but I've seen some servers where it only works with `\n`